# How to fix whitelabel error from angular end without setting or using useHash :true

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-routing, angular-routerlink, white-labelling

We are working on application where frontend is developed in Angular & backend is SpringBoot.
In our application, when we hit the URL it throws "WhiteLabel Error Page".
To resolve this, earlier we have added hash (#) in Angular side but while Okta integration
we need to remove this hash(#) and after removing this hash, again we are getting
"WhiteLabel Error Page".
So, if any one faced this issue then let me know how to resolve it. I know how to resolve it from springboot end but we need to provide fix from angular end. Even someone don't face this but have idea then please let me know. It is very much appreciated.

we have added hash (#) in Angular side but while Okta integration
we need to remove this hash(#) and after removing this hash, again we are getting
"WhiteLabel Error Page".how to resolve it.

Comment: In my opinion it is not possible to handle this from Angular side. It is the server that is responsible for forwarding all requests to index.html and only then Angular can handle routing - in other cases it is not even loaded by the browser.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "angular end" but in your server, you could redirect any thing from your angular to its index. Say your angular is at app.site/angular, then when entering some url like app.site/angular/route1, your server catches /angular/* and redirect to app.site/angular => it will activate angular and its router will handle client route